# page method not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm calling a page method using a jquery function that's somewhat like this:

```
function GetNewDate(thedateitem) {

        ThisMonth = 3;
        TheDay = 1;
        TheYear = 2011;

    DateString = TheMonth + '/' + TheDay + '/' + TheYear;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Pages/CallHistory.aspx/ResetDate",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: DateString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    }) 
};
```

And then, in the code behind file, I have:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ResetDate(DateTime TheNewDate)
{
    var test = 4;
}
```

However, when I put a breakpoint on var test = 4, it never stops there.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: I always use dataType: "text" when calling web methods, just pointing that out, not really sure if that could be causing it.

Comment: How do write the path so that it works? The path is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check exactly what is happening with your jQuery call - I suggest using firebug (or the equivalent in your browser of choice) to trace the javascript and see the response/request.

This will allow you to see any errors being returned from the web page/method.

---

Update:

You should be sending proper [JSON](http://json.org) if you use `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: Absolutely nothing happens. I tried with another ajax call that's in an update panel and when that triggers, I see the call in firefox. However, when I click on the button that triggers the jquery call, it's nada.

Comment: @frenchie - Do you debug the javascript? Is that run?

Comment: @Oded - agreed, Chrome provides the same functionality as Firebug too if you don't want to use FF

Comment: yes, just before the $.ajax line I put an alert("DFGSFGSA"); statement and that one shows up.

Comment: @frenchie - You do realize that the string you are sending is **not** in json format?

Comment: It's my first json/ajax string!! What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: @frenchie - Something like this '{"TheNewDate" : "12/02/2011"}'. See [json.org](http://json.org/)

Comment: Just looked up something. I tried adding this: DateString = "{'TheNewDate': '" + DateString + "'}"; but it's still not going.

Comment: @frenchie - Are you seeing this being sent to the server?

Comment: Now it's saying successFn not defined

Comment: @frenchie - Have you defined functions named `successFn` and one named `errorFn` that are the functions to run in case of success or error respectively?

Comment: ok, I defined the function and I get the error function to trigger: http://localhost:51262/DevSite/Pages/Pages/CallHistory.aspx/ResetDate

Comment: @frenchie - OK... progress is being made. The URL you just posted looks a bit fishy (/Pages/Pages - really?).

Comment: ok, I changed the path and removed the /Pages and now I get the success function to trigger. However, I'm not getting the stop on the breakpoint.

Comment: @frenchie - And you are _definitely_ attached to the webserver process? Did you look at the `Net` tab of firebug and see the request and response come through?

Comment: yes, everything is working fine: I get this message. 200 OK
  1.06s

Comment: When I copy the response I get: {"d":null}

Comment: @frenchie - So, looks like the function returns "nothing", as expected ;)

Comment: @jball - we were all there, trying something for the first time and hitting too many new concepts to even start understanding what is going on ;)

Comment: @Oded - true, you're just sticking to the helpful problem solving longer than I probably would :)

Comment: Yes, in a sense the function returns nothing because that's what it's intended to do. However, I'm looking to debug that on the server with a breakpoint. Is it normal that it's not stopping?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it's one of those things that takes either a  minute if you know and a day if you don't know.

Comment: @frenchie - If you are attached to the process and the URL is right (did you try typing it in?), then it should.

Comment: I guess the setup works since we're getting the success function to trigger. What do you mean by "attached to the process"?

Comment: @frenchie - Debug menu, attach to process. You need the debugger to be attached to the web server process if you want breakpoints to be triggered.

Comment: Ok. I just closed VS and restarted it. IT WORKS!!!!!!! Thank you very much for your help! I can pay back with some VBA or jquery:) check out newtandooricafe.com

Comment: @Oded: I got stuck just a few steps further. Can you look at this if you have a moment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952156/ajax-with-page-method

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the `data` in your `ajax` call properly, referencing the argument name. You'll want to use a JSON string with the parameter names as the properties so that the Asp.NET page method to understand the data properly. E.g.:

```
data: "{'TheNewDate':'" + DateString +"'}",
```

Matthew makes a good point in the comment - you need to serialize your date properly so .Net understands it correctly (all the other primitives work fine, dates are lacking a literal expression format in JS and are therefore problematic). I found [a good example on the SCHOTIME.NET blog](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2008/06/19/jquery-ajax-aspnet-and-dates/) which has a handy little function to serialize a JS `Date` object into an MS compatible JSON string

```
Date.prototype.toMSJSON = function () {
      var date = '"\\\/Date(' + this.getTime() + ')\\\/"';
      return date;
};
```

Your full `ajax` call would then look like:

```
dateValue = new Date(TheYear, TheMonth , TheDay );

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Pages/CallHistory.aspx/ResetDate",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: "{'TheNewDate':" + dateValue.toMSJSON +"}", //<-- the modification
     dataType: "json", 
     success: successFn,
     error: errorFn
 })
```

Comment: You'll need to serialize the date parameter so that asp.net can deal with it on the server.  if you set the data field of the ajax options object as such `Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize({ TheNewDate: new Date() });` then you will be guaranteed that the page will be able to deserialize it.

Comment: @Matthew good point, I've updated the answer to include a simple way to make MS compatible date strings without relying on the `Sys` libraries.